# Pytest unittest-style setup: module setup

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Pytest [documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html) describes four ways to setup/teardown things:

- module level setup/teardown
- class level setup/teardown
- method level setup/teardown
- function level setup/teardown

But in one project it was implemented like this:

```
class TestClass:
    def setup(self):
        ...
    def test_1(self):
        ...
    ...
```

This **setup** method is called around each method invocation, just like **setup_method** from documentation (except that it doesn't take *method* as an argument). But I haven't seen it in the documentation or anywhere else. Why does it work?

Comment: Likely to be compatible with python standard [unittest method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code
https://pytest.org/latest/_modules/_pytest/python.html

I would guess it's inheriting and using

```
def setup(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

It's part of [nose testing framework](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is integrated in pytest. More information you can find [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/nose.html)